# Error 401 while reloading Jwt secured spring Boot React app (and configuration problems)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I'm learning spring boot and react. I have successfully learnt how to use the frontend maven plugin to combine the two. Also JWT kind of works (at least an api call returns what I want while the token is alive and returns error when i set quick expiration time). But react routes work weirdly. I have doubts about what I need to exclude from the web security config java file. If i exclude too much I won't see the homepage. I guess I have found the solution but now reloading doesn't work. Can you please help me find what is wrong here? I want the JWT to work for APIs and I want to be able to access the pages and reload them.
My WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            // dont authenticate this particular request
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/", "/public/**", "/static/**/*", "/login").permitAll().
            // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
            // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I found this file which allows to resolve 404 to index:

```
package kr.ac.korea.sans.jwtlogin.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

     @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
            registry.addViewController("/**").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                        Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                        return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Authentication Service:

```
import axios from 'axios'

class AuthenticationService {

    executeJwtAuthenticationService(username, password) {
        return axios.post('http://localhost:8090/authenticate', {
            username,
            password
        })
    }

    executeHelloService() {
        console.log("===executeHelloService===")
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8090/hello');        
    }

    registerSuccessfulLoginForJwt(username, token) {
        console.log("===registerSuccessfulLoginForJwt===")
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        localStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser', username);
        this.setupAxiosInterceptors();
    }

    createJWTToken(token) {
        return 'Bearer ' + token
    }

    setupAxiosInterceptors() {
        axios.interceptors.request.use(
            config => {
                const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
                if (token) {
                    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            error => {
                Promise.reject(error)
            });
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem("authenticatedUser");
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
    }

    isUserLoggedIn() {

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log("===UserloggedInCheck===");
        console.log(token);

        if (token) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    getLoggedInUserName() {
        let user = localStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser');
        if(user===null) return '';
        return user;
    }


}

export default new AuthenticationService()
```

My Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jwt-login-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=4200 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8090",
  "homepage": "."
}
```

And resoureces properties:

```
server.port=8090
jwt.secret=godaejwt
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern = /**.* --this is for the WebConfig
```

Comment: Your problem is most probably related to the proxy used by react-scripts. If you call your backend on a port different from the one you use in the frontend (i.e. backend runs on :8080, frontend on :80), then you'll get 401s. If this is probably your problem, please respond and I'll turn this into an answer how you can solve this.

Comment: I set up proxy in package.json, i think correctly...
and port 8090 in resources too...see the updated main question body

Comment: Though I think something is wrong in one of the config files...can you please say, have I excluded everyting correctly?